# Moving jQuery UI Sortable elements as groups

Tags: jquery-ui, grouping, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable in which two consecutive elements may be "attached" to each other. When the attach action is performed, I wrap the two "field" elements in a "field-group-container" div in hopes that I would be able to drag both inner "field" elements as a unit.

Oddly enough, this approach works perfectly if I initiate the dragging from the field-group-container's first child (of two children), however, if I initiate the dragging from the second child, the field gets pulled out of the field-group-container. I would like the two field elements to move together regardless of which element is clicked to initiate dragging.

I tried making the "items" sortable option more specific to only allow dragging field-group-containers and fields that are not children of a field-group-container but it looks like the click event is cancelled before it bubbles up to the field-group-container.

In order to find out whether this is an issue with the sortable or my implementation of it, I created a boiled down version to see if I could replicate my issue.

```
<div id="sortable">
    <div class="field">A</div>
    <div class="field">B</div>
    <div class="field-group-container">
        <div class="field">C</div>
        <div class="field">D</div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">E</div>
    <div class="field">F</div>
    <div class="field">G</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/prsGz/

It works exactly as expected!

> This contradicts the behavior I'm observing in my project. In my real
>   implementation the "field" elements have several inner elements such
>   as labels, buttons, etc.

**My question**

1. Does anyone know what would be causing this behavior?
2. What could be causing my two field elements to not move as a unit
   even though they are both wrapped in a parent container?

Comment: how do you initialize the sortable in your application, what are your options?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with `buttons, labels, etc..` in your `<div>` ?